# Сравнение строк без учета слово-позиций

Tags: строки, java

Приветсвую!

Возник вопросец, связанный со сравнением строк.Но сравнение не обычное, а без учета слово-позиций.

Не подскажите ли вы решение этой проблемы..

Пример: Сравнение строк "город Москва" и "Москва город" должны давать положительный результат(true выдавать, например)

Глянул в библиотеку, но подобной функции что-то не нашел, видимо плохо искал..

Заранее благодарю!

**UPD**

Спасибо [[@Yuri_Prime](/users/12334/yuri_prime)](/users/12334/yuri_prime)

Возможно, я сам не так поставил задачу.Может вы посмотрите на нее и расскажите свои мысли. Допустим есть два обычных файла: *Москва город* и *Москва река* (Пока не знаю как лучше, но хотел сделать так Москва-город и  Москва-река)

Нужно по запросу *Москва город* или *город Москва* найти нужный файл)

Может быть какие-то оптимизации провести, что то в самом названии файлов поменять..

Где-то читал, что с сортировкой Array.sort(); как-то так могут быть проблемы с русским языком..

Comment: Извините, что так долго, но всё же отвечу. У меня был схожая задача при создания алгоритма поиска одинаковых ID3 тегов при сканировании большого числа MP3 файлов, для удаления повторяющихся. Я думал решать её так: из всех строк удалить пробелы, знаки препинания и прочее лишнее, оставить только буквы и цифры, затем привести строки в нижний регистр. После этого уже работать с такой цифробуквенной кашей и искать совпадения с использованием RegExp'ов для задания точности плюс-минус один символ. Возможно, такой подход поможет и вам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Описанное вами сравнение строк очень хорошо подходит под определение [множества](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html): набор элементов без учёта порядка.

```
one = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("город москва".split(" ")));
two = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("москва город".split(" ")));
return one.equals(two);
```

Для поиска файлов используйте `HashMap<Set<String>, File>`

```
map.add(one, file);
map.get(two);
```

Всё запросы работают за `O(str.length())`. Очень удобно.

- Если нужно case-insensetive — перед добавлением используйте `str.toLowerCase()`.
- Если нужен учёт числа слов ("ох ох" ≠ "ох") — вместо Set используйте [Multiset](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html)
- И будьте осторожны с разбиением строки на слова. Рекомендую использовать [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html).

Answer (score 4):

Я вижу такой вариант: взять две строки, если нужно - привести к одному регистру, разобрать на массивы букв, отсортировать их и сравнить. Судя по примеру, если массивы одинаковы, то и строки похожи.

Comment: Это да, но при этом подходе «апельсин» и «спаниель» окажутся равны.

Comment: Таки правда, извините за нетерпимость, но это медленное решение с кучей ошибок второго рода. Не понимаю кто наставил столько плюсов.

Comment: @Jofsey Ничего страшного, спасибо за конструктивную критику. Возьму ваше решение на вооружение, возможно, пригодится.